# Building Google V8 with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, v8

I am attempting to build google V8 with Visual Studio 2013 according to [Building with Gyp](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building%20with%20Gyp). However, I am getting  this error on practically every .vcxproj file in my solution explorer:

```
Error   12  error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/H,' C:\v8\tools\gyp\cl  v8_base_3
```

According to [the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc2y4ddf(v=vs.120).aspx), "/H restricts the length of external names." and "/H is deprecated; the maximum length limits have been increased and /H is no longer needed."

I'm not sure if this is a problem with visual studio versions or if I need to remove this flag from some code somewhere. Any chance I could get some help? Thank so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is pretty self-explanatory.

`Error   12  error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/H,' C:\v8\tools\gyp\cl  v8_base_3`.

i.e After `/H` the compiler expects a numeric argument. However it encountered a comma `'/H,'`. Could you paste the snippets of your `.vcproject` file?

Did you try providing a numeric argument after `'/H'`?

Comment: Then is should be an easy bounty haha :) I'm pretty new to c++. The reason I am confused is in the error list the file is listed as "cl" and there is no line or column given. Just the project in which the error occurred. I don't know exactly where to go to see where the error occurred.

Comment: The error doesn't complain about `cl`. It only complains about numeric argument after `/H`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the error. I believe there was a version problem and somehow I was trying to use deprecated code. I reinstalled the files and it built just fine.